# Code structure: flat or tree? for react components

Tags: reactjs, directory-structure

I am designing directory structure for my react app. I am wondering should I make it into a tree like

```
|-component
  |-layout
  | |-BaseLayout
  | |-AdminLayout
  | |-UserLayout
  |-page
    |-Home
    |-Upload
```

Or should I make the structure flat like this.

```
|-component
  |-BaseLayout
  |-AdminLayout
  |-UserLayout
  |-Home
  |-Upload
```

Which one will be more scalable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react official docs:

> If you’re just starting a project, don’t spend more than five minutes on choosing a file structure. Pick any of the above approaches (or come up with your own) and start writing code! You’ll likely want to rethink it anyway after you’ve written some real code.

File structure is more about code readability. In your case, first approach is more readable as you're making sub-directories for your main components that makes it more concise and understandable.
This is a good read about file structuring of our app:
[How to better organize your React applications](https://medium.com/@alexmngn/how-to-better-organize-your-react-applications-2fd3ea1920f1)